# How to multiply integer digits between them?

Tags: ruby

I want to my `n` to multiply with next number for example if n=99 i want it to 9*9 and then return a result, and then i want the result (9*9 = 81 then 8*1 = 8) to multiply until it becomes 1 digit.

Here's my code:

```
def persistence(n) 
  if n <= 9
    puts n
  else
    n.to_s.each_char do |a|
      a.to_i * a.to_i unless n < 9
      puts a.to_i
    end
  end 
end
```

and i want it to return this:

```
persistence(39) # returns 3, because 3*9=27, 2*7=14, 1*4=4
             # and 4 has only one digit

persistence(999) # returns 4, because 9*9*9=729, 7*2*9=126,
              # 1*2*6=12, and finally 1*2=2

persistence(4) # returns 0, because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

Comment: what do you think is the issue with the code? You just mentioned the problem you are trying to solve, and not the trouble with the code you have written.

Comment: the issue is that the code i wrote doesn't output what i'd like it to output :D
for example persistence(39) outputs: 3 and then 9

Comment: Note that there's a big difference between "method returns value" and "method __prints__ value"

Comment: also, check your code again. It is not even printing "3" and "9". It'll be printing "39" "39". You are not changing `n` anywhere.

Comment: just realized you edited code. nvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def persistence(n)
   i = 0
   while n.to_s.length != 1
     n = n.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i).reduce(:*)
     i +=1
   end
   i
end

persistence(39) #=> 3
persistence(999) #=> 4
```

Other version:

```
def p(n, acc)
  return acc if n <= 9
  p(n.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i).reduce(:*), acc+1)
end
def persistence(n)
  p(n, 0)
end
```

I will leave the breaking down of method and understanding what's happening and what is the difference b/w two variations to you. Will love to see your comment explaining it.

Comment: `each_char`, `map` with `#to_proc`, `reduce`? That's overwhelming! :)

Comment: BTW, ruby 2.4 brings `Integer#digits`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Wow. I must upgrade to new Ruby asap! Missing out on lot of new stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
def persistence(n)
  0.step.each do |i|
    break i if n < 10
    n = n.digits.reduce(:*)
  end
end

persistence 4                  #=> 0
persistence 39                 #=> 3
persistence 999                #=> 4
persistence 123456789123456789 #=> 2
```

Regarding the last result, note that `2*5*2*5 #=> 100`.